# advantages of embedding text files compared to reading from disk

Tags: .net, performance, file-io, text-files, embedding

I have a .net application that has a set (about 100 ) text files that are opened - read - manipulated and saved as a new file for each time the user runs the process. in some cases the same "template" file could be used hundreds of times in one process. So they are basically templates I use to create the required files for my application. Currently I have included them in a folder of my project and have "copy Always" selected for the "Copy to Output Folder option in my solution. so they are copied, stored and accessed on the local PC.

My question - Is there an advantage to embedding these files into my solution? specifically would the IO process run quicker if the files are embedded rather than going to the directory and opening the file and reading the file...

additionally if you have any input on other reasons for doing or not doing this I would like to hear them. These files will be updated from time to time. It is my understanding that i would have to recompile each time a file was saved. Part of the reason the files are being used is to avoid this so I would desire a performance boost to make up for the loss of easy updates.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not much in the way of input here from anyone so I ran a test.
I thought I would share the results in case anyone else ever wants to know.

I tested the time frame to open an embedded file, read it and save the lines into a new file saved on local PC and close the embedded file. I set a loop for 1000 times to call this routine and it took 11 seconds to create 1000 files.

In another routine I opened the same file that was saved to the local disk instead of being embedded in the executable, read it and saved it as a new file on the local PC. Also set a loop for 1000 times to call this routine and it took 2 seconds.

I ran that multiple times and got the same results each time.
I additionally ran test one and saw results and shut the app down restarted and ran the test again. I just wanted to be sure there was nothing that was in memory. The results were the same each time.

So in short the embedded files took longer to read and write than accessing the files off the file system.